# devtools::load_all() not working from bash script

Tags: r, bash, devtools

I am currently developing a package (using `renv`) and, within RStudio, everything works fine. I can press CTRL + SHIFT + L to invoke `devtools::load_all()`, load the package, and then use the functions, etc.

I also have a script that uses this development package, call it `test.R`. I can source this within RStudio and it works as expected.

```r
print("loading environment")
renv::load()
print("loading package")
devtools::load_all()
print("doing the thing")
print(nrow(mtcars))
```

Until about a week ago, I could also call this script from bash and it would run successfully. The script is:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
cd ~/Documents/my_pkg
/usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla --verbose test.R
```

However when I run this script now, I get the following output:

```bash
running
  '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin/R --no-echo --no-restore --vanilla --file=test.R'

[1] "loading environment"
[1] "loading package"
ℹ Loading mypkg
my_script: line 5: 35695 Killed: 9               /usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla --verbose test.R
```

I have tried:

- going back to a known working commit -> no longer works
- setting my `PATH` variable to the same (longer) path that I see in RStudio with `Sys.getenv('PATH')` -> doesn't work

I'm also not sure what automatic updates or other changes might have happened in the meantime that would affect this. Presumably it's something in the wider system, but I'm stumped.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? How might I go about debugging it?

**PS:** Roxygen also no longer works

```bash
==> devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

ℹ Updating mypkg documentation
ℹ Loading mypkg

Exited with status 137.
```

Comment: Two more things I've tried: cloning the repo in a new directory (same problem), building documentation in another RStudio package project (works fine). So presumably there's something in the `renv` setup specific to this package.

Comment: FYI, passing `--vanilla` to R is almost never what you want, and is prone to break things, precisely because it prevents reading the user configuration. 10 times out of 10, when somebody passes `--vanilla` they actually want `--no-save --no-restore`.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually traced this to a Java dependency problem, coming from the package `mailR`. I installed some packages using Homebrew around this time and I think it updated Java, breaking the requirements for mailR. Solved it by moving to an email package without a Java dependency.

The debugging approach was removing dependencies from the DESCRIPTION file until I found the package causing the problem. Then it was guesswork from there.